# Find the nearest regular polygon, given a side length and an approximate radius

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I want to create a regular polygon with a given side length, *s*, and an *maximum* radius, *r<sub>1</sub>*.

[image: A regular polygon]

The radius value needs to be decreased (or increased if it simplifies things) to the closest length, *r<sub>2</sub>*, that will create a regular polygon, i.e. with the given side length *s*, and any integer number of sides, *n*.

So from *s* and *r<sub>1</sub>* you need to calculate a new, nearby *r<sub>2</sub>* and the associated *n*.

Is this possible? It seems like something that should be straight forward, but I'm not sure where to start.

[Edit: changed apothem to radius in the question, as radius would ultimately be more helpful.]

Answer (score 1):

Solution sketch:

The circumradius $r$ of a [regular polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) is $$r=\frac{s}{2\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}$$

Solve for $n$ and calculate the value with the given $r$ and $s$. Remove the fractional part of $n$ ([floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)). This is your $n$. Then calculate the new $r$.