# Calculate sides of polygon given side length and circumradius.

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons

Given $R$ and $a$ below, is it possible to calculate $n$ with just these values?

Example, say I have a circumradius of $10$, and a side length of $1$, is it possible to calculate $n$, rounded to the closest integer?

This is how far I've come (Wolfram Alpha's answer):

[image]

But I would like to somehow eliminate $c_1$ and have no clue how.
Using the above values, I tried to calculate $n$ using $R=1.3066$ and $a = 1$ which should result in $n=8$ but got nowhere close.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you have those extra terms in the denominator; your formula should just be $n=\frac{\pi}{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{2R}\right)}$. For $R=10$ and $a=1$ that yields $n \approx 63$.

Comment: There is not always an exact solution.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/963697/1204862 or https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/regular-polygon